# Equivalent of `int.bit_length()` in Julia

Tags: int, julia

What is the equivalent of Python's [`int.bit_length()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length) in Julia?

> `int.bit_length()`: Return the number of bits necessary to represent an integer in binary, excluding the sign and leading zeros

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Julia there is the [`ndigits`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.ndigits) function.

> `ndigits(n::Integer; base::Integer=10, pad::Integer=1)`
>
> Compute the number of digits in integer n written in base base (base
>   must not be in [-1, 0, 1]), optionally padded with zeros to a
>   specified size (the result will never be less than pad).
>
> #### Examples
>
> ```
> julia> ndigits(12345)
> 5
>
> julia> ndigits(1022, base=16)
> 3
>
> julia> string(1022, base=16)
> "3fe"
>
> julia> ndigits(123, pad=5)
> 5
> ```

You want to use it with the `base = 2` keyword argument:

```
julia> ndigits(32, base = 2)
6
```